# Проблема с передачей json

Tags: php, json, mysqli, json-encode

Во время передачи с `Mysql-запроса` `php` странно себя ведет с кирилицей хотя в `header` стоит `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

**Вопрос:** *Что ето может быть?*

Comment: кодировку бд `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` использовал?

Comment: нет но не пойму где ето писать? (в php документе?)

Answer (score 1):

Дело не в json encode.
Чаще всего при создании таблицы в mysql не указали UTF-8

Пример:

```
   `about` VARCHAR(666) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT ''
```

Также можно еще попробовать указать charset=utf8, в самом mysql подключении.

```
public static function get_some_data_from_sql($get_some)
        {
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=база;charset=utf8", DB_USER, DB_PASS);
            $sth = $dbh->prepare($get_some);

            $sth->execute();
            $result = $sth->fetchAll();

            return $result;
        }
```

Comment: в таблице стоит `utf8_unicode_ci` но когда это делать на хостинге то проблем нету

Comment: нужно зайти в php my admin  (или workbench) и посмотреть таблицы, какой там charset, чтобы было понятно где неправильная кодировка (при чтении данных, при записи в mysql, или же при выводе из mysql), но чаще всего это неправильно задан charset при создании таблицы...

Answer (score 1):

если например вот так подключаешь базу

```
$твоя_переменная_для_сonnect = mysql_connect (параметры);
```

то попробуй после mysql_select_db написать

```
mysql_query ("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", "");
mysql_query ("set character_set_client='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Comment: подключаюсь через `mysqli->connect`